# How to set center point of rectangle after rotate and resize, keep old location

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I tried set center point after rotate and resize but something is going wrong.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
 
 $('#left').on('click', function(){
 
  rectGroup.rotate(-1);
  layer.draw();
 
 });
 
 $('#right').on('click', function(){
 
  rectGroup.rotate(1);
  layer.draw();
 
 });
 
    function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('Image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
        }

        image.position(topLeft.position());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
            image.width(width);
            image.height(height);
        }
    }
    function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Konva.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 8,
            name: name,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
            update(this);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
            group.setDraggable(false);
            this.moveToTop();
        });
  anchor.on('dragstart', function() {
   img.oldSize = {w: img.getWidth(), h: img.getHeight()};
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
            group.setDraggable(true);
      setRectZoomPoint();
            layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            this.setStrokeWidth(4);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            this.setStrokeWidth(2);
            layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
    }
 
 function setRectZoomPoint(){
 
  var dif = {x: img.x(), y: img.y()};
  rectGroup.move({x: dif.x, y: dif.y});
  rectGroup.getChildren().each(function(child){child.move({x: -dif.x, y: -dif.y})});
  
  //set center point
  rectGroup.move({x: -img.oldSize.w / 2, y: -img.oldSize.h / 2});
  rectGroup.move({x: img.getWidth() / 2, y: img.getHeight() / 2});
  rectGroup.offset({x: img.getWidth() / 2, y: img.getHeight() / 2});
  rectGroup.get('.centerPoint')[0].position({x: img.getWidth() / 2, y: img.getHeight() / 2});
  layer.draw();
 
 }
 var angle = 0;
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var img = new Konva.Image({
        width: 200,
        height: 137
    });
 img.oldSize = {w: 200, h: 137};


    var rectGroup = new Konva.Group({
        x: 180,
        y: 50,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(rectGroup);
    rectGroup.add(img);
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');
 addAnchor(rectGroup, 100, 69, 'centerPoint');

    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.onload = function() {
        img.image(imageObj1);
  setRectZoomPoint();
        layer.draw();
    };
    imageObj1.src = 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/78/73/53/240_F_78735333_o3qJe4bT5ciwldLIjVDulFKrDAV3jGYO.jpg';
```

```html
<button type="button" id='left'>left</button>
 <button type="button" id='right'>right</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.6/konva.min.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
```

Comment: Perhaps read up about matrix operations - done it in Math when I was 13

Comment: rotation matrix didnt work.

Comment: @johnDeph - seems to work ok if I just rotate it a few clicks left or right then stretch it then continue to rotate. If you fixed it already add an answer to explain what you did. This is a useful example of scale and rotate so please do not delete the question.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat setRectZoomPoint() this function calculates new center point after rotate and resize from new width, height and old position but main problem is cant keep old location. Try it rotate 45degree and resize bit long and u will see problem

Answer (score 1):

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
 
 $('#left').on('click', function(){
 
  rectGroup.rotate(-1);
  layer.draw();
 
 });
 
 $('#right').on('click', function(){
 
  rectGroup.rotate(1);
  layer.draw();
 
 });
 
    function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('Image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
        }

        image.position(topLeft.position());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
            image.width(width);
            image.height(height);
        }
    }
    function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Konva.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 8,
            name: name,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
            update(this);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
            group.setDraggable(false);
            this.moveToTop();
        });
  anchor.on('dragstart', function() {
   img.oldSize = {w: img.getWidth(), h: img.getHeight()};
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
            group.setDraggable(true);
   setRectZoomPoint();
            layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            this.setStrokeWidth(4);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            this.setStrokeWidth(2);
            layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
    }
 
 function setRectZoomPoint(){
  
  // setting position of rectangle and anchors to 0,0
  var dif = {x: img.x(), y: img.y()};
  rectGroup.getChildren().each(function(child){child.move({x: -dif.x, y: -dif.y})});
  
  var radian = toRadians(-rectGroup.rotation());
  var absPos = {x: rectGroup.x(), y: rectGroup.y()};
  //old CenterPoint thats before resize
  var oldCP = {
   x: absPos.x - absPos.x * Math.cos(radian) - absPos.y * Math.sin(radian), 
   y: absPos.y - absPos.y * Math.cos(radian) + absPos.x * Math.sin(radian)
  };
  //new CenterPoint thats after resize without angle
  var newCP = {
   x: rectGroup.x() + img.getWidth() / 2 - img.oldSize.w / 2 + dif.x, 
   y: rectGroup.y() + img.getHeight()/ 2 - img.oldSize.h / 2+ dif.y};
  //must calculate real central point with angle
  var realCP = {
   x: oldCP.x + (newCP.x * Math.cos(radian) + newCP.y * Math.sin(radian)),
   y: oldCP.y + (newCP.x * -Math.sin(radian) + newCP.y * Math.cos(radian))
  }
  
  rectGroup.position({x: realCP.x, y: realCP.y});
  rectGroup.offset({x: img.getWidth() / 2, y: img.getHeight() / 2});
  rectGroup.get('.centerPoint')[0].position({x: img.getWidth() / 2, y: img.getHeight() / 2});
  layer.draw();
 
 }
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var img = new Konva.Image({
        width: 200,
        height: 137
    });
 img.oldSize = {w: 200, h: 137};


    var rectGroup = new Konva.Group({
        x: 300,
        y: 200,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(rectGroup);
    rectGroup.add(img);
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(rectGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');
 addAnchor(rectGroup, 100, 69, 'centerPoint');

    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.onload = function() {
        img.image(imageObj1);
  setRectZoomPoint();
        layer.draw();
    };
 
 function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * (Math.PI / 180)
 };

 function toDegrees(radians) {
  return radians * (180 / Math.PI)
 };
    imageObj1.src = 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/78/73/53/240_F_78735333_o3qJe4bT5ciwldLIjVDulFKrDAV3jGYO.jpg';
```

```html
<button type="button" id='left'>left</button>
 <button type="button" id='right'>right</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.6/konva.min.js"></script>
```

The problem has been solved by rotation formula in canvas coordinate system.